# Number of target values in the one prediction

Tags: python, statistics, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I use python's scikit-learn module for predicting some values in the CSV file. I am using Random Forest Regressor to do it. As example, i have 8 train values and 3 values to predict - which of codes i must use? As a values to be predicted, I have to give all target values at once **(A)** or separately **(B)**?

**Variant A:**

```
#Readind CSV file
dataset = genfromtxt(open('Data/for training.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]
#Target value to predict  
target = [x[8:11] for x in dataset]
#Train values to train 
train = [x[0:8] for x in dataset]
#Starting traing
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=300,compute_importances = True) 
rf.fit(train, target)
```

**Variant B:**

```
#Readind CSV file
dataset = genfromtxt(open('Data/for training.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]
#Target values to predict  
target1 = [x[8] for x in dataset]
target2 = [x[9] for x in dataset]
target3 = [x[10] for x in dataset]
#Train values to train 
train = [x[0:8] for x in dataset]
#Starting traings
rf1 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=300,compute_importances = True) 
rf1.fit(train, target1)
rf2 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=300,compute_importances = True) 
rf2.fit(train, target2)
rf3 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=300,compute_importances = True) 
rf3.fit(train, target3)
```

**Which version is correct?**

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"8 train values and 3 values" is probably best expressed as "8 features and 3 target variables" in usual machine learning parlance.

Both variants should work and <del>yield the similar predictions</del> as `RandomForestRegressor` has been made to support multi output regression.

<del>The predictions won't be exactly the same as `RandomForestRegressor` is a non deterministic algorithm though. But on average the predictive quality of both approaches should be the same.</del>

**Edit**: see Andreas answer instead.

Comment: But, why in case (A) i have much more accurate predictions than in case (B)?

Comment: No idea. I thought it was doing the same internally. Maybe it's not the case. I will to check the source code.

Answer (score 4):

Both are possible, but do different things.

The first learns independent models for the different entries of `y`. The second learns a joint model for all entries of `y`. If there are meaningful relations between the entries of `y` that can be learned, the second should be more accurate.

As you are training on very little data and don't regularize, I imagine you are simply overfitting in the second case. I am not entirely sure about the splitting criteria in the regression case but it takes much longer for a leaf to be "pure" if the label-space is three dimensional than if it is just one-dimensional. So you will learn more complex models, that are not warranted by the little data you have.

Comment: So the only way I can get SO karma seems to be that you don't know the answer ^^ That way I'll never catch up with larsmans ;)

Comment: Actually i want to predict 24 values. I have 11 values to train. Every training variable have 32000 samples. I am predicting output of some chemical process - and yes there are meaningful relations between the entries (sum of all 24 outputs must be = 100), What can you recommend me solve this problem?

Comment: Try both an pick the method that works best by measuring the score you want to optimize using cross validation.